# How to get list of all projects with versions in the azure DevOps server from WPF or Windows application

Tags: c#, wpf, git, tfs, azure-devops

I want to list and display all project files in Azure DeveOps server from a windows/WPF application.
Ealier My application retrieve data from TFS server. Now our repository is changed and Now Azure devops server is used instead of TFS.
I am looking for equivalent of below code which is used in TFS. I want to do same operation with Azure DevOps Server.

**Sample Code to get all project files and objects from TFS**

```
 Uri tfsUri;            
        string OutPutFolderDB, DirectoryNextTo, Path;
        tfsUri = new Uri("http://" + serverURI + "/testProjectCollection");
        var targettfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.ICommonStructureService stuctureService =
       targettfs.GetService<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.ICommonStructureService>();

        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.ProjectInfo[] projects = stuctureService.ListAllProjects();
        VersionControlServer vcs = targettfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
```

I would like to know similar kind of above code which is used in Azure devops server. My repository is git.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at any documentation?

Comment: I couldn't find documentation.could you plz share if any @Daniel Mann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recommend that you can use REST API to [list all projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) in the power shell script.

Sample:

```
$connectionToken="{PAT}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$OrgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0-preview.4" 
$ListProject = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $OrgUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
$ListProjectCount = $ListProject.count
Write-Host  $ListProjectCount 

$ListProjectName= $ListProject.value.name

ForEach ($Name in $ListProjectName)
{
Write-Host  $Name
}
```

Result:
[image]

We also can use client API to list the project, corresponding Code in C#:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("{org url}");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", {credentials});

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("_apis/projects?$top=250&stateFilter=All&api-version=1.0").Result;


    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        //failed
    }
}

// Convert responseString into a json Object
RootObj jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(responseString);
Console.WriteLine("Found " + jsonObj.Count + " projects");

//Do stuff
foreach (var obj in jsonObj.Value)
{
    //foreach project...
}
```

**Update1**

[List all repositories:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

We can get the repo ID, then You can use the API below to list repo files:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo ID}/items?recursionLevel=Full&api-version=4.1
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How to include credentials @Vito Liu-MSFT

Comment: Do you mean the token? If yes, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to manage it.

Comment: Thank you @Vito Liu-MSFT  . I would like to get all the content in a repository . is there any rest api to get all files in a project ? My exact requirement is the replacement of existing sample code.

Comment: Thank you so much @ Vito Liu-MSFT for your help. Actually I had spelling mistake issue too.Now I  can list all files.

Comment: please have a look at this question too. @Vito Liu-MSFT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380193/how-download-file-form-azure-devops-sever-to-a-specified-path-using-api-and-c-sh

Answer (score 0):

If you want download all these:

[click here](https://github.com/hendrickcastro/toolbash/tree/main/getAllProjects)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31307186)